# Regex match a string if is not followed by digits in one case

Tags: python, regex

I have the regular expression:

```
 ^[-\s]+|Not Specified$
```

I get a match on all of the following strings:

```
--
Not Specified
- - -                    eV
-270 - 1000                    deg C
```

but I want to get only on the first three.

I don't want to catch word like:

```
 MTF, Depth, Focus, Blur
sub-micron
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could match either `Not Specified` or match at least a single `-` without matching digits or a newline:

```
^(?:Not Specified|[^\r\n\d-]*-[^\r\n\d]*)$
```

**Explanation**

- `^` Start of string

  - `(?:` Non capturing group
  - `Not Specified` Match literally
  - `|` Or
  - `[^\r\n\d-]*-` Match 0+ times any char except a digit, `-` or newline, then match `-`
  - `[^\r\n\d]*` Match 0+ times any char except a newline or digit
- `)` Close group
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/8K7dWo/1)

Note that `\s` also matches a newline, if that is intended you can omit the `\r\n` so that the negated character class will match thenewlines.

Comment: your regex catch string like " MTF, Depth, Focus, Blur" which I don't want to match. Updated my question.

Comment: @user3541631 The pattern does not match those words https://regex101.com/r/fwKorN/1

Answer (score 1):

You need to add parenthesis. The \D matches anything other than a decimal digit:

```
^(\D+|Not Specified)$
```

You can even break down to:

```
^\D*$
```